# How do you add PGPLOT for C?

Tags: c, cygwin

How do you add the PGPLOT library? I'm specifically coding in C, using Cygwin64 as the runtime environment, gcc as the compiler, and Windows 7 as the computer operating system.
I'm trying to get the PGPLOT 5.2 library found here:
http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/ 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As the cygwin package is not present you need to compile and install it,
by yourself

http://www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot/install.html